# Would a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I need a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to observe a preference for the whole life of my application, either if its on background or foreground. Would registering on Application's onCreate and never unregistering ever since cause a leak?

As far as i understand, i think not, as the application process seize to exist when Application object is evacuated from memory, so i guess that this `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` will be evacuated as well. correct me if im wrong...

Comment: I don't think this should be an issue, but I am interested as to whether or not there is a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to do it this way since there is no static context. After your application gets destroyed, so does your `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. Memory leak could happen only if one of them is defined as `static` so as long as you don`t do it, everything is OK.

Comment: I dont think that static have anything to do with that, if the app process is dead so do all of the static objects defined in the app code AFAIK...